# Caret symbol does not work with grep

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu

This does not work

```
grep -h '^zip' log*
```

this works

```
grep -h '[^bg]zip' log*
```

The log* files definitely contain a file named `zip` because the second command prints out the file name. But the first does not print anything at all. I try several and see that the caret symbol only works as negation in brackets. Outside of the bracket, it does not mean to indicate that something following it would be in the beginning of the word. 
What is wrong here? I am using ubuntu 12.4

Comment: What version of grep are you using?  
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.10

works for me for what you are doing.

Comment: it has nothing wrong with grep. It just that I misunderstood how crate works. I thought that it indicates what following it would be in the beginning of a word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> beginning of the word

`^` marks the beginning of line, not word. `"foo zip"` will not match against `^zip`, but `"zip foo"` will. If you want to match `zip` at the beginning of a word, use this:

```
grep \\bzip
```

`\b` marks a word boundary, but you need to double up on escapes because your shell will strip one. (`grep '\bzip'` also works.)